# Why the number of linearly independent columns of a matrix doesn't change by if we apply Row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can anyone please tell me why the number of linearly independent columns of a matrix doesn't change even if we apply row operations on the matrix?

The column space does change by row operations but I don't understand why the number of independent columns remains the same.

Comment: Hints: elementary row operations can be represented by elementary matrices. Consider the homogeneous system $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ that has a nullity of $n$, elementary row operations mean multiplying both sides by $E$, but since $E$ is invertible, the system is the same $EA\vec{x} = A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, so the nullity is unchanged, and then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row operations change columns and change the column space, but they *preserve* linear dependence relations among the columns!

For example, say $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the first two columns, which become $C_j'$ after a row operation. You can verify that if $aC_1+bC_2=0$ then $aC_a'+bC_2'=0$.

Hence a set of columns is a basis for the column space if and only if it is a basis after the row operation.

Comment: Thank you, I understood how linearly dependent columns remain linearly dependent after row operations but I was asking about how the number of linearly Independent ones remains the same. But thank you, I learned something else or maybe I didn't understand the response fully.

Comment: ??? Say there are three independent columns in $A$. Then those three columns remain independent in $A'$, so $A'$ has at least three independent columns. Similarly, if $A'$ had more than three independent columns then the same would be true of $A$. So the maximum number of independent columns stays the same. (Also a set of columns spans the column space in $A$ if and only if it spans in $A'$, since spanning can be expressed in terms of linear combinations...)

Comment: I verified that if $aC_1+bC_2=0$ then $aC_1'+bC_2'=0$ where $a, b \neq0$. So row operations don't change the number of dependent cols. But how to show number of independent columns remain the same.